# Прокси сервер

Tags: прокси, кэширование

Здравствуйте. Скажите пожалуйста, что именно кэшируется на прокси-сервере ( если мы к примеру кэшируем информацию с новостного сайта, где контент меняется каждые 5 минут)?

По видам прокси-сервера делятся на прозрачный и обратный? Если так, то суть каждого вида?

Answer (score 1):

> что именно кэшируется на прокси-сервере

Кэшируется то, что сказано кэшировать :) И, если прокси правильный, то что кэшировать а что нет, что сколько времени хранить в кэше - ему сообщает удалённый сервер для каждого элемента отдельно. А он эту информацию принимает и переваривает.

> контент меняется каждые 5 минут

Любой контент состоит из множества элементов. Зайдите на страничку любого "новостного сайта" и посмотрите, сколько там картинок, подключаемых скриптов, стилей и прочего. Подумайте, что из этого стоит сохранять в кэше, а что нет.

> По видам прокси-сервера делятся на прозрачный и обратный? Если так, то суть каждого вида?

[Первый же тык в гугл](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80)